# SVG image is not updating onMouseOver

Tags: jquery, svg

When the user hovers on the button, the default SVG icon should be replaced with an animated icon and vice versa. But the catch is, when the user tries to hover on the different button multiple times, the default image is not getting replaced with an animated SVG icon. Here is the [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/toggle-svg-image-pmdj8)

Comment: It seems to work fine

Comment: Nope, its not working.

Comment: I can't find in your code an element with id="app"